# How to alter the Browser's Refresh Event and trigger a custom function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

As you all know, when we hit the refresh button, the entire page starts to reload. But I dont that, I only want to refresh some portions, which need to be refresh in case of a need.

I know, I can use ajax to reload a piece of content. But I want to attach this ajax function while the user clicks the refresh button or presses F5 or presses Ctrl+F5.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Don't do this**, don't *attempt* to do this, you're breaking the behavior that the user has come to expect from their browser, this should not be overridden in any way.  Nothing outside of the frame containing your page should be affected by your code, that's the *user's* browser, not yours.

Refresh has a purpose, they want to re-load the content, what if your script breaks, what if it's a JavaScript error?  They may *need* a browser refresh to fix the issue...this is one of a thousand valid reasons, none of which should behave *unexpectedly*.

Disregarding the *why* you shouldn't above, you *can't* do this, not in every browser...for exactly the reasons I provided above plus many more.

Comment: Well, you are propably right, but some contents which have properly loaded, dont need to be reloaded, like menubar, banner, why do we need to reload that

Comment: @Starx - You can provide a refresh icon of some sort *in* your page, but don't try to override the basic functionality of the browser.

Comment: @Starx: This is why the browser will cache them. It's not your problem to deal with.

Comment: Yes, I agree on this, But I just want to know if there is a way to accomplish this

Comment: @Starx: There isn't, advertisers would abuse the hell out of it if there were :)  When you think of why a feature doesn't exist, also consider "how could it be exploited/abused?"...therein usually lies the reason.